# What are my options if I need to store data on behalf of a user in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am building a Microsoft Teams application and I need to store sensitive user data (access tokens and some additional stuff) for each user using my application.

My requirement is that this data can only be accessible from the user and no one else - and it needs to potentially serve tens of thousands of users. Furthermore, this data shall be accessible from any Microsoft product (i.e. not bound to MS Teams, but let's say, as long as I get a the JWT, then I would be able to access the data).

What are my options using Azure? Is there some kind of storage I can use OOTB? Or, would I need to select an Azure service for this? If yes, which service would be the best? Can I instantiate such service for ALL the users I need to serve, or would I need a separate instance for each tenant the user is coming from (e.g. its company?).

Thanks a lot for helping me out, I tried to figure this out already and I got some ideas, but I am still confused.

Comment: (1) Store it in Azure Keyvault or SQL can be used to store you access tokens/additional info and retrieve/use it when its needed. (2) A lot options exists in Azure. So you need to do the match whats best suits your requirement.

Comment: @Dev thanks for the answer. Let's say I use the Key Vault, as far as I understand this is a multi-tenant service, and therefore I could technically assign a Key Vault for each customer that I have. Is this something that I have to provision? For example, getting the tenant ID from the user and creating a new Key Vault if not existing?
What I need to do is keep customer data separate from each other.

Comment: As i said you lot of options in Azure, so you need to decide which suits your scenario. Say, If you're using keyvault then it will help you to Secrets Management, Key Management and Certificate Management. So choose what you want to store, implement a business logic, store/retrieve the data till you use it.

Comment: Hi @abianche You can use azure tables to store and retrieve the access tokens , users data and the messages. Again it depends on your requirement.

Comment: Hi @abianche, are you still facing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirement, you can store the sensitive user data with the following options

- **Azure keyvault:** For Secrets Management, Key Management and Certificate Management.
- **Azure storage tables:** To store and retrieve the access tokens, users data and the conversation.